# Creating controls

Tags: silverlight

I am designing a silverlight application in which i have a image control in the left top corner and when i click the button and drag it to the form i should get duplicate of that control and dragged into my form.

Please help me with the code

I am trying to create the control dynamically in mouseleftbuttondown event but the controls are not being created.

Xaml

```
<UserControl xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"  x:Class="Workflow.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
    <Canvas x:Name="layout" Width="800" Height="600" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="21.jpg" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Stretch="Uniform" 
             MouseLeftButtonDown="MyImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" ></Image>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl>
```

Code

```
private void MyImage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            b = cs.LoadControl();
            layout.Children.Add(b);
        }

List<Ellipse> block = new List<Ellipse>();
        public Ellipse LoadControl()
        {
            Ellipse btn = new Ellipse();
            block.Add(btn);
            btn.Height = 50; btn.Width = 100;
            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 0);
            btn.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            Canvas.SetTop(btn, 50);
            Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 50);
            return btn;
        }
```

Comment: Show us the code so far. lets see why it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 0)` which has 0 for alpha, which makes your control transparent. What if you try `Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0)`?

Comment: @Sathish:  If this answers your quesion you should click the big tick that you see on the left to show that it is the accepted answer.  Ordinarily you would also upvote it, afterall if the answer wasn't good you wouldn't accept it.